# How do I use the Spacing Utility Classes in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, meteor, bootstrap-4

In this [article](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/whats-new-in-bootstrap-4) I saw Bootstrap 4 Spacing Utility Classes, and he uses `m-b-lg` in `className`.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 m-b-lg">
        <!-- column-small-50%, margin-bottom-large -->
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I use it on meteorjs with react nothing happens. Am I missing something or missing a plugin?

```
<div className="container-fluid">
    <div className="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 m-t-lg">
        <h1 className="text-xs-center"> Login </h1>
        <form>
            <div className="form-group">
                <input type="email" className="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email"/>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <input type="password" className="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password"/>
                <p className="text-xs-center"><a href="/signup"> Forgot your email or password?</a></p>
            </div>      
            <div className="form-group">
                <button className="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit"> Login </button>
                <p className="text-xs-center"> New to Arcademy? <a href="/signup"> Sign up now.</a></p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Refer to the [Spacing](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/spacing/) (Bootstrap v4 alpha) documentation.

The classes are named using the format: `{property}-{sides}-{size}`

> Where size is one of: * `0` - for classes that eliminate the `margin`
>   or `padding` by setting it to `0 * 1` - (by default) for classes that
>   set the margin or padding to `$spacer-x`or `$spacer-y * 2` - (by
>   default) for classes that set the margin or padding to `$spacer-x *
>   1.5` or `$spacer-y * 1.5 * 3` - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to `$spacer-x * 3` or `$spacer-y * 3`.

So use `m-t-3` instead of `m-t-lg`.

Comment: I use m-t-100 nothing change. <div className="container-fluid"> <div className="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 m-t-100"> <h1 className="text-xs-center"> Login </h1> </div> </div> @bass jobsen

Comment: you shoud use `m-t-1`, `m-t-2`, or `m-t-3`

Comment: The official Boostrap 4.0 spacing documentation is [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) (although still in beta at the time of this comment).

Comment: Maybe it's me, but the documentation LOOKS marvelous and complete. Until you try to use it.  Bootstrap is fantastic, the effort to build it and maintain it for all of us is huge. The documentation was also a lot of effort as well, but some was done by someone who knows the answers and doesn't need it, or by someone who is being told what the that answer should be, but doesn't understand it.  For example, in this instance, is the documentation telling me to add CSS to support these utilties? Or showing me CSS what is already defined? If you read thru the whole page, the contexts aren't clear.

Answer (score 86):

**Bootstrap 5 beta - update 2021**

Now that Bootstrap 5 has RTL support, the concept of `left` and `right` have change to `start` and `end`. Therefore the `*l-` and `*r-` spacing utilities have changed

`pl-*` = `ps-*`
`pr-*` = `pe-*`
`ml-*` = `ms-*`
`mr-*` = `me-*`

**Bootstrap 4 -update 2020**

The Bootstrap 4 [spacing utils have changed](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) since the original answer (for v4 alpha). Now the syntax is simply:

- **margins:** m{sides}-{size}
- **padding:** p{sides}-{size}

**Examples..**

`mb-2` = margin bottom 2 spacing units
`m-0` = no margins
`pt-3` = padding top 3 spacing units
`p-1` = padding all sides 1 spacing unit

There are now **6 sizes** (0-5) that represent a portion of the standard `.5rem` spacer unit. Additionally, **x-axis** (left/right) and **y-axis** (top/bottom) utils have been added:

`my-2` = margin top & bottom 2 spacing units
`mx-0` = no margins left & right
`px-3` = padding left & right 3 spacing units

And, the spacing utils are now responsive. The smallest `xs` breakpoint is implied when no breakpoint is used.

- **margins:** m{sides}-{breakpoint}-{size}
- **padding:** p{sides}-{breakpoint}-{size}

`mt-md-2` = margin top 2 spacing units, on `md` (and up)
`py-sm-0` = no padding top & bottom, on `sm` (and up)

[Bootstrap 4 Spacing Utils Demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/kaWaobOUD8/bootstrap-4-spacing-utils)

---

Related: [Bootstrap 4 spacing bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44025566/bootstrap-4-spacing-bug/44025627#44025627)

Comment: I didn't see anything in the documentation mentioning using multiple classes.  For instance p-3 pb-1 seems to be only recognizing the p3 spacing despite the pb-1 class coming after the p-3 is declared.  Is this supposed to be supported?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44025566/bootstrap-4-spacing-bug/44025627#44025627

Comment: Type-o: The example `pr-*` = `me-*` should be `mr-*` = `me-*`.
And I wish they would have kept the "l" and "r" sides!  :-|

Answer (score 5):

Basically its only works from 0 to 3. m-t-0, m-t-1, m-t-2, or m-t-3