# Is there equivalent of m-t-1 class of bootstrap 4.x in bootstrap 3.x?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

As stated in the title: I see in bootstrap 4 (alpha version) there are some classes to work with margins and paddings like `m-t-1`, `p-a-1`, etc.

I know... I can use custom classes. But just for information, is there equivalent classes of `m-t-1`, `p-a-1` and so on in bootstrap 3?

Tnx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the [spacing utility classes](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/spacing/) for padding and margins were introduced in **Bootstrap 4**, so there is no equivalent in Bootstrap 3.

**Examples..**

`mb-2` = margin bottom 2 spacing units
`m-0` = no margins
`pt-3` = padding top 3 spacing units
`p-1` = padding all sides 1 spacing unit
`py-3` = padding top & bottom (y-axis) sides 3 spacing units

More on the [spacing utils](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42960338/171456), and [what's new in Bootstrap 4](https://medium.com/wdstack/bootstrap-4-whats-new-visual-guide-c84dd81d8387).