# What is instead of `p-a-1` class now?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I read the [Pro ASP.NET Core MVC 2 Seventh Edition](https://www.apress.com/br/book/9781484231494) book by Adam Freeman. In the code examples author uses the `p-a-1` CSS-class of Bootstrap for the `form` tag, but I don't see such class for Bootstrap v3.3.7.

I assume that this is an obsolete class, but I can't find any information about it in Google. I also do not understand what name I am to use now instead of `p-a-1` in Bootstrap v3.3.7.

Comment: This is your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43047374/is-there-equivalent-of-m-t-1-class-of-bootstrap-4-x-in-bootstrap-3-x the class "pa-1" is in Bootstrap 4 but not 3.

Comment: I looked it before. But Adam Freeman writes that in the book he uses Bootstrap 3... And he uses `p-a-*` instead of `pa-*`.

Comment: I downloaded and checked 3.3.7 Bootstrap css just now and no pa-1 or p-a-1 class exists there. There is a "pa-1" class in Bootstrap 4, however.

Comment: @Rob, read my first comment more attentivly, please.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a class "p-a-1" in Bootstrap v4 use "p-3"

```
.p-a-1 {padding: 1rem 1rem !important;}    /*v4.0.0-alpha# */

.p-3 {padding: 1rem !important;}   /*v^4.0.0 */
```

Version 3.3.7 does not use relative values, e.g. 1rem. Assuming that the basic font size is about 15px, you can use this class in place of the specified class in Bootstrap v3.3.7:

```
.panel-body {padding: 15px}
```

You could also create an additional CSS-File, where you put in the styles for the class which Adam Freeman uses.

Comment: Please don't write in any other languages than English on StackOverflow. (I'm obviously not talking about programming languages...)