# Bootstrap 4 spacing bug?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap 4 has [Spacing Utilities](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/spacing/) to adjust margins and paddings with simple CSS classes.

**Theoretically**, I could do something like this:

```
<div class="d-inline-block bg-inverse p-5 pb-0 m-5 mb-0"></div>
```

And this should be an element with **paddings and margins** on each side **except at the bottom**. Right?

But that isn't happening. Instead, `pb-0` and `mb-0` are being overwritten by `p-5` and `m-5`, as you can see here:
[example in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/80dssmxh/).

---

`pb-0` and `mb-0` are defined after `p-5` and `m-5` in the original source, and all of the attributes used in these classes have `!important`. So `pb-0` should overwrite the `padding-bottom` defined by `p-5` and `mb-0` should overwrite the `margin-bottom` defined by `m-5`.

I created another example where I defined these classes in the same way, but in this case, they are working as expected: [comparison example in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/80dssmxh/1/).

---

#### Why these Bootstrap 4 classes are not working as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spacing utils use `!important` so, using `pb-0` to override `p-5` isn't going to work because `p-5` follows `pb-0` in the `bootstrap.css`

To get it [working like you want](https://www.codeply.com/go/6hSIEizfMd) set the specific sides...

`<div class="d-inline-block bg-inverse pb-0 px-5 pt-5 mb-0 ml-5 mt-5"></div>`

And, since DIV doesn't have padding or margins by default, you don't really need the `*-0`...

`<div class="d-inline-block bg-inverse px-5 pt-5 ml-5 mt-5"></div>`

https://www.codeply.com/go/6hSIEizfMd

---

Also see, [when it's OK to use !important](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

Comment: Browsers indicates `p-5` in `_spacing.scss` line 12 and `pb-0` in `_spacing.scss` line 15. But after taking a look at the bootstrap files, the `-0` classes are generated first in the `@each` loop in `_sizing.scss`. So yes, as you said `p-5` is defined after `pb-0`. But this looks like something wrong for me, I can't find a situation where you need a specific side padding being overwritten by a general padding. I solved it rearranging the `$spacers` array in `_variables.scss`. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, that works in your case, but others may want the reverse. For example, suppose you want to zero out the padding, and then add it back to one side eg:`<div class="d-inline-block bg-info ml-5 p-0 pt-5">Text</div>`. Currently in BS4 this works, but if you change the order of classes it won't work,

Comment: Yeah... that's true. I was going to open a proposal on GitHub, but with your example now I have seen that there is no ideal solution for this.

Comment: Thanks for the insight and great question!