# Bootstrap v4 padding negation pl-??? & p-??? doesn't look intuitive

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I've been testing Bootstrap V4

if you have:

```
<div class="p-3 pl-0"></div>
```

Shouldn't padding be 3 3 3 0 instead of 3 3 3 3 ?
All though in the source code, p-3 will always be listed after pl-0 due to their code. But how to achieve this without going for repetitive solution like:

```
<div class="pt-3 pr-3 pb-3 pl-0"></div>
```

or

```
<div class="py-3 pr-3 pl-0"></div>
```

?

Both seem less initiative as  p-3 + pl-0, any advice?

Comment: You will need to set the specific sides as seen in the related question. It's because of the order of the `p-*`  classes in Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: Can you link me to existing question, I don't want to open another discussions also thank you for your answer.

Comment: It's at the top: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44025566/bootstrap-4-spacing-bug

Comment: My bad, thank you very much!

Comment: No, not bad... good question!