# Why is there no vertical space between Bootstrap 4 rows

Tags: bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am trying to migrate from Bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 4. Bootstrap 3 had vertical space between rows by default, but this is not the case in Bootstrap 4. Can someone please explain why? Or am I missing something in my HTML?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-9">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            Card01
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            Card01
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            Card02
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            Card02
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use the Spacing Utility Classes on Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363194/how-do-i-use-the-spacing-utility-classes-on-bootstrap-4)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Bootstrap 5 (update 2021)**

Bootstrap 5 has [new gutter classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/) that are specifically designed to adjust the gutter for an entire row. Additionally, there is now the concept of **vertical gutters** to adjust the vertical spacing between rows and columns that wrap inside each row.

- use `g-0` for no gutters
- use `g-(1-5)` to adjust horizontal & vertical gutters via spacing units
- use `gy-*` to adjust vertical gutters
- use `gx-*` to adjust horizontal gutters

**Bootstrap 4 (original answer)**

Rows no longer have `margin-bottom` in Bootstrap 4. Use the new spacing utils (`mb-4`).

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42960338/171456.