# Bootstrap 4 responsive spacing (padding) not working

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I want to give certain top-bottom padding of 80px and left-right padding of 0 inside my parent div id (about-us). So I've tried bootstrap 4 responsive spacing (padding) i.e. py-80 but it's not working here with me.

```
<div id="about-us" class="py-md-80">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <h3 class="display-5 text-capitalize">about us</h3>
    <p class="text-muted">Divide have don't man wherein air fourth. Own itself 
     make have night won't make. 
     A you under Seed appear which good give. Own give air without fowl move the 
     dry first 
    heaven fruit, dominion she'd won't very all.</p>
    <img src="./imgs/signature.jpg" alt="signarure" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Read the docs on how the spacing utility classes work: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/

There are no arbitrary px sizes such as `80`. There sizes 0-5 and auto which respresent different rem units...

> Where ***size*** is one of:
>
> 0 - for classes that eliminate the margin or padding by setting it to
>   0
>   1 - for classes that set the margin or padding to
>   $spacer * .25
> 2 - for classes that set the margin or
>   padding to $spacer * .5
> 3 - for classes that set the
>   margin or padding to $spacer
> 4 - for classes that set the
>   margin or padding to $spacer * 1.5
> 5 - for classes that
>   set the margin or padding to $spacer * 3
> auto - for classes that set
>   the margin to auto

Also see: [How do I use the Spacing Utility Classes on Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363194/how-do-i-use-the-spacing-utility-classes-on-bootstrap-4/42960338#42960338)