# How to apply bootstrap margins to specific breakpoints

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want to only apply a bootstrap margin on xs and sm devices

I've inserted mt-4 mt-sm-4 on an element so that it only targets extra small and small devices.

This works however I'm finding that the margin is also being applied on larger destkop devices so I had to zero out the margins by including mt-md-0 and mt-lg-0. Is there a reason why I have to zero out the margins as I thought that if I targetted the xs and sm devices then it would only apply there. I'm just not sure how bootstrap works, ie. if I apply a class to a smaller device, does that mean it will apply to that device plus all larger devices?

Comment: Both `mt-4` and `mt-sm-4`? That will always be `mt-4`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mt-4 mt-md-0`.

That applies:

- margin-top 4 units on xs and small
- margin-top 0 units on md (and larger)

Also see: [How do I use the Spacing Utility Classes on Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363194/how-do-i-use-the-spacing-utility-classes-on-bootstrap-4/42960338#42960338)

Comment: It's about the difference between absolute and relative sizing in the Bootstrap framework. The relative values are given in percent which can be adjusted to different pixel heights.

Comment: No, not with margins. They're *all* `rem` units. The 4 represents `$spacer * 1.5` and $spacer is `1rem`.