# What is the meaning of $spacer in bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-4, sass

I am new to bootstrap. I came aloing this documentation on bootstrap:

```
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/spacing/
```

Here is writed that when we write for example mt-1 that means:

```
1 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * .25
```

what means in this situation $spacer * .25 ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$spacer` is a SASS variable. By default it's value is `1rem`. Therefore mt-1 is `margin-top:.25rem;`

The value for each of the 6 spacing units (0-5) are derived from the $spacers SASS map variable...

```
$spacers: (
    0: 0,
    1: ($spacer * .25),
    2: ($spacer * .5),
    3: $spacer,
    4: ($spacer * 1.5),
    5: ($spacer * 3)
)
```

Result...

```
mt-1 = .25rem
mt-2 = .5rem
mt-3 = 1rem
mt-4 = 1.5rem
mt-5 = 3rem
```

Related: [How do I use the Spacing Utility Classes on Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363194/how-do-i-use-the-spacing-utility-classes-on-bootstrap-4/42960338#42960338)